# How to make numbers look like groups of 3 digits separated with space

Tags: split, abap

I would like to change my currency style; right now my style is `1234567.00`, but I want it to be like `1 234 567`.

Second example: `12345.00` should be `12 345`.

How would be the best way to do this conversion?

Right now I use:

```
SPLIT x_string AT '.' INTO l_curr1 l_curr2.
```

This gives the `l_curr1` the value of `1234567`.

How should I continue to do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to reverse the string, add an " " in every 3 symbols and then reverse the string again, but I am think, is there an better solution?

Comment: If the input is `1234567.89', what do you expect for digits after the decimal point?

Comment: By the way, we developers usually don't need to bother about number formats, because users can choose it (transaction SU3): 12.345,67 or 12,345.67 or 12 345,67

Answer (score 5):

One possibility is to use an [edit mask](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abapwrite_to_options.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_13@13@) :

```
DATA: chars  TYPE c LENGTH 30.
DATA(number) = 1234567.
WRITE number TO chars USING EDIT MASK 'RR___ ___ ___ ___'.
ASSERT chars = '      1 234 567'. " <== ASSERT just for demonstration purpose
```

You may apply some additional logic to suit your needs, like removing leading spaces (CONDENSE), etc.

Answer (score 4):

Check out embedded expressions. You can format as you like. Example:

```
lv_string = |{ lv_source COUNTRY = 'GB' }|.
```

You can also use CURRENCY and NUMBER depending on your needs. NUMBER can be set to RAW, ENVIRONMENT or USER.

Comment: There are no countries defined by default for groups with **space** delimiter, so @User13664463 should first check in his system if it has been setup for the concerned country (if any).